# ¿Como se introduce una url de API en Java Script?

Tags: javascript, array, api, url

Estoy trabajando con un juego donde el usuario debe adivinar una palabra oculta. Con cada partida nueva el juego cambia esa palabra oculta en base a un array en JS. Pero necesito vincular con una API, ya tengo la url pero necesito saber donde insertarla para que tome las palabras de allí.

Comment: Hola Richard, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprenadas como funciona la plataforma. Por favor, presioná [edit], agrega el código que has realizado y un ejemplo de los datos que recibes desde API.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar fetch para hacer una petición de tipo get a la Api y obtener la información

ejemplo: solo cambia la url por la Api que quieres hacer la petición

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1') .then((response) => response.json()) .then((json) => console.log(json));
```